# Where do I add Context Provider in NextJS 13 using app router?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, next.js13

In React you have something like this:

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

And you would wrap your Providers around the the `<App />` but in NextJS v13.4+ `app router` this ` does not exist.  What is the right way to create a globally available context?

Also, when importing 3rd-party libraries to use in the `context`, I assume things like useEffect/useState will create issues. Is there a way to handle this in create a `context provider`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question and I'm glad you asked.

Here's how I did it.  Let's start at the "end" of the step up and the drill down.  (Then we'll look at how to use them ie. how to get/set the variables in your `Pages`.)

So instead of having an `<App />` at your root element render, you'll use the RootLayout instead.  This does get created by NextJS and lives here: `/App/layout.js`

```
import './globals.css';
import { Providers } from './ContextProviders/Providers';

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
    return (
        <html>
            <body>
                <Providers>{children}</Providers>
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

Okay ^ now that is your `<Providers>` wrapper where you can import your own providers or 3rd-party ones.

Let's see how to define `<Providers />`.  Notice the `'use client'` notation to prevent the issues with using "client side" third party libraries on Server components. Notice how the multiple Providers should successively wrap each other.  I put this here: `/app/ContextProviders`.

```
'use client';

import { UserProvider } from './UserProvider';
import { MyOtherProvider } from './MyOtherProvider';

export function Providers({ children }) {
    return <MyOtherProvider><UserProvider>{children}</UserProvider></MyOtherProvider>;


}
```

Finally, let's look at how to create a Provider.

```
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const UserContext = createContext();

export const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [userID, setUserID] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        // do stuff like setting userID
        // you might access a db or other service here
        setUserID('asdfasdf-asdf-asdf-asdf-asdfasdfasdf');
    }, []);

    return <UserContext.Provider value={{ userID, setUserID }}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>;
};
```

In case you're confused about why value has that double curly brace, it is just shorthand for creating objects in code via assignment with key-value pairs (ie. an object literal).  In other words, with less syntactic sugar it's this:

```
return <UserContext.Provider value={{ userID: userID, setUserID: setUserID }}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>;
```

Or even more explicitly, this:

```
const sharedValues = 
{ userID: userID, setUserID: setUserID }

return <UserContext.Provider value={sharedValues}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>;
```

So, how do we use this in a page?

```
// /app/page.js
import react, { useContext } from 'react';
import UserContext from './ContextProviders/UserProvider'

export default Page() {

const { userID, setUserID } = useContext(UserContext);

return (<div>Hello World! {userID} </div>)
}
```

If you want to read more from the Vercel team look [here](https://vercel.com/guides/react-context-state-management-nextjs).